# Is it possible to employ the sliding transition from createMaterialTopTabNavigator in createMaterialBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

`createMaterialTopTabNavigator` has a sliding transition from screen to screen as you press the tabs, whereas `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` uses a fading-in animation when it transitions.

Is there anyway to use the transition from the former with the latter?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment. The material bottom tab navigator uses [react-native-paper's BottomNavigation component](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/bottom-navigation.html) which doesn't support this type of animation. If that component were updated to support this, then it could be exposed in react-navigation.